# How to run an app with compose.yaml, Dockerfile, Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Advise me please how to run a project. There are compose.yaml with a postgres, Dockerfile with description of app's image files in a Spring Boot project. Should I use docker-compose up in order to start the container with the postgres, then docker build, docker run to start the container with the app and eventually the app should be started? So the main method in such case shouldn't be run manually?

Comment: I'd normally expect `docker-compose up -d --build` to do everything you need.  Can you [edit] the question to describe in a little more detail what problems you're running into, including a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are correct in your approach.

- **Start the Postgres Container with docker-compose**:
  Use docker-compose up to start the Postgres container defined in your docker-compose.yaml file. This will create and start the Postgres container, making the database accessible to your Spring Boot application.
- **Build the Docker image for Your Spring boot application:**
  Use docker build to build the Docker image for your Spring Boot application. This will create an image containing your application code and dependencies.
- **Run the Docker Container with Your Spring boot application:**
  Use docker run to run the Docker container from the image you built in the previous step. This will start your Spring Boot application inside a container.
- **Starting the Application:** Once the Docker container with your Spring Boot application is running, the main method of your Spring Boot application will be automatically executed. You don't need to run the main method in this case manually. Your application will start and listen to incoming requests.

By following this workflow, you can start both the Postgres database and your Spring Boot application in Docker containers, allowing them to communicate.

> More info:

Basic steps to run an app with compose.yaml, Dockerfile, Spring Boot

**Create a Dockerfile:**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/your-application.jar /app
CMD ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

Above sample for jdk11. Replace application.jar with the actual name of your Spring Boot application JAR file.

**Create a docker-compose.yaml File:**
Here's an example of a Spring Boot application and a PostgreSQL database:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/your_database_name
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: your_database_username
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: your_database_password
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: your_database_name
      POSTGRES_USER: your_database_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: your_database_password
```

Replace your_database_name, your_database_username, and your_database_password with your actual database configuration.

**Build and Run with Docker Compose:**
Run the following command to build and start your services defined in docker-compose.yaml:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

This command will build the Docker image for your Spring Boot application, start both the Spring Boot application and the PostgreSQL database container, and make them communicate with each other.

**Access application:**
Once the containers are up and running, you can access your Spring Boot application at http://localhost:8080 (assuming your Spring Boot application listens on port 8080).